# How to select the three highest outputs by select sum from other table?

Tags: php, mysql

in my current PHP project I would like to display the three most viewed posts on my website.

The number of views per post is stored in a different table, like the general data of the post. In this table an entry of the daily views is made for each day and each post.

Currently I can get all the data from the general post table,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `article_category_id` = '1' DESC LIMIT 3";
$most_viewed_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($most_viewed_post_query)) {

        $article_id = $row['article_id'];
        $article_categorie = $row['article_category_id'];
        $article_title = $row['article_title']; 
        $article_author = $row['article_author'];
        $article_date = $row['article_date'];
```

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `article_category_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `article_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `article_author` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `article_date` date NOT NULL,
  `article_content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `article_tag` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_german2_ci;
```

and from the views table I can only get the sum of one post by ID.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(day_views_count) AS article_views FROM days_views WHERE view_id = $article_id";
$get_article_views = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_article_views);
    $article_views = $row['article_views'];
```

```
CREATE TABLE `days_views` (
  `view_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `day_views_count` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_german2_ci;
```

I have no idea how to write the two SELECTS together to make the output fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(day_views_count) AS article_views 
FROM days_views 
WHERE view_id = $article_id
ORDER BY article_views LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join table `articles` with an aggregatd query that pulls out the  of the three most viewed `view_id`s from `article_views`, like:

```
select a.*
from articles a
inner join (
    select view_id 
    from article_views 
    group by view_id
    order by sum(day_views_count) desc
    limit 3
) v on v.view_id = a.azrticle_id
```

Comment: that is not working for me. in my result i got only the first three entries of the datatable, but not the thre most viewed posts

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select a.*
from articles a
inner join (
    select view_id 
    from article_views 
    group by view_id
    order by day_views_count desc
    limit 3
) v on v.view_id = a.article_id
```

The other suggestion where sum(day_views_count) is used, will sum the entire column for each entry thus it won't sort properly.
My suggestion orders it by the count, then takes top three. Does it work?

Comment: unfortunately not, I get the same result here